# r Dockerfile with containeRit results in closure error

Tags: r, docker

My goal is to create a simple R script file, which does some connecting to Google Cloud Storage (GCS), updates an object received and puts it back into GCS.

This is my script file (its just for testing purposes):

```
library(googleCloudStorageR)

## set authentication details for non-cloud services
options(googleAuthR.scopes.selected = c("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write"))

## download or do something
something <- tryCatch({
  gcs_get_object("test/test.csv", 
                 bucket = "somebucketname")
}, error = function(ex) {
  NULL
})

## create a new entry (row) with arbitrary values

fake_id = 0
if(exists("something")){
  fake_id = max(something$id)+1
} else {
  fake_id = 1
}

something_else <- data.frame(id = fake_id,
                             name = paste(sample(letters, 10, replace = TRUE), collapse = ""))
something <- rbind(something, something_else)

## authenticate on GCE for google cloud services
googleAuthR::gar_gce_auth("rstu________________6ef1.json")

tmp <- tempfile(fileext = ".csv")
on.exit(unlink(tmp))
write.csv(something, file = tmp, row.names = FALSE)
## upload something
gcs_upload(tmp, 
           bucket = "somebucketname", 
           name = "test/test.csv")
```

So now I want to run this on a virtual machine, so I want to create a Dockerfile. Therefore I use `containeRit()`. When running the function it results in the following error.

```
container <- dockerfile("testScript.r",
                        copy = "script_dir",
                        cmd = CMD_Rscript("testScript.r"),
                        soft = TRUE)
```

> Error:
> Object of type 'closure' is not subsettable.